# Adding Output Layer with Python

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm having issues troubleshooting how to get my python code to automatically add my output layer to my current map in ArcPRO. I've included the code snippet below along with my error.

Snippet:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
aprxMap = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
newLayer = (("FinalSurveyPts" + "_" +str(projName +".shp")))
aprxMap.addLayer(newLayer)
aprx.save()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
del aprx
```

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Grid Tool\Goshawk Survey Grid Tool.py", line 144, in <module>
    aprxMap.addLayer(newLayer)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\utils.py", line 191, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\_mp.py", line 2560, in addLayer
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.addLayer(*gp_fixargs((add_layer_or_layerfile, add_position), True)))
ValueError: FinalSurveyPts_WaltonPeak.shp
```

Comment: You pass a tuple of tuple of strings to the `addLayer` method. But it expects a tuple of tuple of something) and a boolean. According to the error messega: `(add_layer_or_layerfile, add_position), True))`. Why would it need this crazy/wierd/confusing input?